# Win 7 Connection keep change and Reset user costumization always fail

Tags: windows-7, proxy, connection, reset

I am running Windows 7, I don't have any visual studio in my laptop.
Every day after starting up my connection change to using proxy.
some times change into automaticly will only last for several hour/minutes, after that it's change back to proxy.
Please advice for solution ?

Also When I trying to reset my connection into default, removing user costumization always fail.
Please help .... ?

Comment: This a local or domain account?